# Creating global variable within eventListener whitin the same "for"

Tags: javascript

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
    var span = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        span[i].innerText = parseInt(span[i].innerText) +1;
    });
}
```

the inner span doesnt "see" the same [i] i use for buttons. the console returns "not defined" any suggestions on how to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your event handler (`click` on your `button`), will run later, and that time, `i` is something else. You should use a **closure** to keep it internal:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'); 
var span = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', (function (i) {
        return function (event) {
          span[i].innerText = parseInt(span[i].innerText || 0) + 1;
        };
    }(i)));
}
```

```html
<button>A</button>
<span class="counter"></span>

<button>B</button>
<span class="counter"></span>

<button>C</button>
<span class="counter"></span>
```